# twistd in Twisted cant be run in window

Tags: python, window, twisted, xmpp

in command prompt i type >>twistd echobot.tac

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Scripts\twistd.py", line 18, in ?
  from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
ImportError: No module named twisted.scripts.twistd
```

the twistd is at C:\Python26\Scripts\twistd.py

```
#!c:\python26\python.exe

# Copyright (c) 2001-2009 Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.


### Twisted Preamble
# This makes sure that users don't have to set up their environment
# specially in order to run these programs from bin/.
import sys, os, string
if string.find(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]), os.sep+'Twisted') != -1:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]),os.pardir, os.pardir)))
if hasattr(os, "getuid") and os.getuid() != 0:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))
### end of preamble


from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
run()
```

when i type

```
from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
```

in python ,it can be run

Comment: What version of twisted is this, and how did you install it?

Comment: oww ... i forgot already ... but this problem is in window ... now i use ubuntu , work like charm

Comment: Certain versions of Twisted did not quite install themselves properly on Windows.  I believe this is fixed with current versions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting path.. something like this in cmd:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
```

and then run twistd